# Go "x/crypto/ssh/knownhosts" always reports a key mismatch

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to use the `knownhosts` package to read the `known_hosts` file and provide a `HostKeyCallback` for `ssh.ClientConfig`. I have verified that I can connect to the host I am using for testing manually using `ssh` on the command line, and that the host is in fact in the `known_hosts` file via `ssh-keygen -F`. However, `ssh.Dial` *always* reports a key mismatch error.

My code:

```golang
import (
    "net"
    "os/user"
    "path"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/knownhosts"
)

func DialSSH(conf *config.Standard) (*ssh.Client, error) {

    var err error
    var u *user.User
    var keyCallback ssh.HostKeyCallback

    if conf.RemoteKey != nil {
        keyCallback, err = ssh.FixedHostKey(conf.RemoteKey)
    } else {
        if u, err = user.Current(); err == nil {
            keyCallback, err = knownhosts.New(path.Join(u.HomeDir, "/.ssh/known_hosts"))
        }
        if err != nil {
            keyCallback, err = knownhosts.New("/etc/ssh/known_hosts")
        }
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    host := net.JoinHostPort(conf.Ip, conf.Port)
    config := ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: conf.User,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(conf.Pass),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: keyCallback,
    }

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host, &config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return client, nil
}
```

It checks for a user-level `known_hosts` file, falls back to a system-level `known_hosts` if there's no user-level file, and returns an error if neither one exists. That never happens, so I know it is finding the `known_hosts` file. But then the call to `ssh.Dial` *always* fails with a key mismatch.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the `knownhosts` package just broken?

Comment: Are you sure `conf.RemoteKey` is a valid *public* key?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg That branch works. The problem occurs when reading the known_hosts files and using the HostKeyCallback returned by knownhosts.New

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's nothing wrong with the code, *and* the `knownhosts` package is not broken (or at least, this particular behavior wasn't a bug).

I wrote a custom key callback to inspect the keys that were being checked, and it turns out that

1. The target host has multiple keys.
2. The command line `ssh` program receives one of those keys, and that one was in the `known_hosts` file.
3. `ssh.Dial` was, for reasons I do not know, receiving a *different* key.

Manually adding all of the keys for the target host to `known_hosts` with `ssh-keyscan` resolved the issue.

It would still be good to know why command-line `ssh` and programmatic `ssh.Dial` were seeing different keys, though.

Comment: Simple explanation: In the beginning, an ssh client and an ssh server negotiate what type of key (RSA, DSA, ED25519 et al, iirc) they can process and which one they prefer. The key they settle on is then used for the remaining steps. Most likely, the configuration of your go client differs from the configuration of your CLI client.